# Understanding the proof that $c_0$ is a closed subspace of $\ell^\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, proof-explanation

The problem is given: [source](http://folk.uib.no/ima083/courses_files/Solutions.pdf)

> Let $c_0$ be a space of real sequences $x = \{x_n\}_{n = 1}^\infty=0$ converging to $0$. Let $\ell^\infty$ be a set of real sequences $w = \{w_k\}^\infty_{k=0}$ furnished with the norm $\|w \|_\infty = \sup_{1 \leq n \leq \infty} |w_n|$. Prove that $c_0$ is closed in $\ell^\infty$

The pdf says

> [image]

**TL;DR**: Please check whether my recap of the proof is correct? As detail as possible so I have a deep understanding of what is really going on. Thank you

1. Start with a sequence in $c_0$, our goal is to show that its limit $\omega  \in \ell^\infty$ is also in $c_0$. This limit exists by completeness of $\ell^\infty$.
2. Denote this sequence by $(x_n^k)_{k=1}^{\infty} = ( \{x^1_1,x_2^1,\dots \}, \{x_1^2, x_2^2,\dots \}, \dots)$. As the objects in $c_0$ are sequences, we have a sequence of sequences.

A quick remark: My intuition tells me that since the elements of $c_0$ all converge to $0$, it would seem to make sense to me that this sequence (of sequences) will also converge to a sequence (of sequences) to $0.$ That is $\omega = 0.$

3. Instead of showing that the entire sequence (of sequences) $(x_n^k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ converges to a limit (of sequences) $(\omega^{k}_n)_{k =1}^{\infty}$ (this should be a sequence of constant sequences), we show that each term of $(x_n^k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ converges to each term of $(\omega_n^k)_{k = 1}^{\infty}$. Note that for a fixed $k$, $\omega_n^k = (\omega_1^k, \omega_2^k, \dots, )$, so the elements are numbers
4. I am guessing $(\omega_n^k)_{k =1}^{\infty}$ is another sequence in $c_0$? I don't know why you want $(\omega_n^k)_{k =1}^{\infty}$to be in $\ell^\infty$ in the first place.
5. I am also guessing that when they say

> Take $\epsilon >0$ and $N_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sup_{1 \leq n \leq \infty} |x_{n}^{k} -  \omega_n| < \epsilon/2$ for all $k > N_0$.

They are using the convergence of $(x_n^k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$

6. I am guessing that when they say

> For each $k $, choose $N_1 \in \Bbb N$ such that $|x_n^k| < \epsilon/2$ for all $n > N_1$ and $k > N_0$

They are using the convergence of the **elements** in $(x_n^k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$, which all go to $0$.

Remark: As opposed to (5), they don't really know if the sequence (of sequence) $(\omega_n)$ really go to a sequence (of sequences) of $0$s. So they denote this "mystery" limit of sequence (of sequences) by $(\omega_n^k)_{k = 1}^{\infty}$

(7) I think the conclusion now is that $0 = \omega \in c_0$?

(8) Would it be more firm to make $k,n > \max \{N_1,N_1\}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1. Start with a sequence in $c_0$, our goal is to show that its limit $\omega\in\ell^\infty$ is also in $c_0$. This limit exists by completeness of $\ell^\infty$

Incorrect. To prove that a set is closed, we start with a *convergent* sequence in  that set, and show that the limit is contained in the set. The existence of limit is assumed, not obtained from completeness.

"Quick remark" is totally wrong. Take $x_n = (1+1/n,0,0,0,\dots)$. Then the limit of $x_n$ is $(1,0,0,\dots)$, not the zero sequence.

I don't know where you got  $\omega_n^{(k)}$ from, or what it means; consequently I can't make any sense from your items 3 and following.

---

Advice: since you are getting confused by "sequence of sequences" business, change the notation to functions. A sequence of real numbers if just a function $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb R$. So, you have a sequence of *functions* $f_n:\mathbb N\to\mathbb R$. They converge to some function $g$ in the sense that $\|f_n-g\|_\infty\to 0$. The goal is to prove that the function $g$ satisfies $\lim_{k\to\infty} g(k)=0$.

By the definition of limit, we must do the following: given $\epsilon>0$, find $K$ such that $|g(k) |<\epsilon$ whenever $k\ge K$. To this end, we

- find $N$ such that $\|f_n-g\|_\infty<\epsilon/2$ whenever $n\ge N$.
- find $K$ such that $|f_N(k)|<\epsilon/2$ whenever $k\ge K$. (This is possible since $f_N\in c_0$)
- observe that $|g(k)|\le |f_N(k)|+|f_N(k)-g(k)| <\epsilon$ whenever $k\ge K$, as required.

Comment: Um, doesn't that mean your example $1 + 1/n \not\in c_0$? Also, $\omega_n^k = (\omega_1^k, \omega_2^k, \dots, )$, the answer don't show the "$k$" in the upper script because it is believed the each term in the sequence is the same.

Comment: I added more under the horizontal line, since you continue to confuse two different kinds of indices here (as in your previous comment).

Comment: oh okay I think the function point of view clears up more. Is the sequence $\{ g(k) \}_{k \geq 1}$ in $c_0$ or $\ell^\infty$? I know that's not too important, but I still want to know.

Comment: The function $g$ is originally assumed to be in $\ell_\infty$ (meaning it's bounded), but the proof shows that it's in $c_0$ (meaning that $\lim_{k\to\infty} g(k)=0$).

Comment: So then when we started with a convergent sequence in $c_0$, is this not $ \{ g(k) \}$? Because the conclusion is that the limit $g(k) \to 0$.

Comment: $g$ is not a sequence anymore (precisely to avoid this confusion), it's  a function. It's  a point. It's a single element of your space. The sequence is $\{f_n\}$, and the limit of this sequence is $g$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17321/discussion-between-sidht-and-thursday).

Comment: And I also think you mean $f_n : \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You think many wrong things, and this is one of them. I'd prefer if you spent less time reiterating own misconception, and more time absorbing a correct argument. I'm done here.