# Understanding $c_0$ is a closed subspace of $\ell^{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

[Understanding the proof that $c_0$ is a closed subspace of $\ell^\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/940629/understanding-the-proof-that-c-0-is-a-closed-subspace-of-ell-infty?rq=1) I came across this proof and I have a simple question, does this proof only shows that $c_0$ is only a closed subset in $\ell^{\infty}$? Do I need to show that $c_0$ is a linear subspace in $\ell^{\infty}$ for the subspace part?
Any help would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the author of that post only tries to prove that $c_0$ is a closed *subset* of $\ell^\infty$, in spite of the title of the post. Actually, the statement is “Prove that $c_0$ is closed in $\ell^\infty$.” So, yes, you still have to prove that it is a subspace (which is very easy, by the way).

Comment: To show that I need to show : It is closed under addition.
Show it is closed under scalar multiplication.
Show that the vector 0 is in the subset. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Note that the vector $0$ here is the null succession.

Comment: Is it sufficient enough only to show that it's closed under scalar multiplication?

Comment: Also I have another question. Why the proof uses absolute value instead of norm? should it be using infinite norm instead? Thanks.

Comment: THe person who posted the only uses $\lvert\cdot\rvert$ applied to nubers. Note that the accepter answer uses $\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty$. And, no, proving only that it's closed under scalar multiplication is **not** enough.